# Auth0 Authentication for .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt, auth0

I have a web API created in .net core 1.1. I have used Auth0 to Authenticate it with social logins. The client type chosen is “API’s BETA”.
I have another web application created in .net core 1.1 which is using Another Auth0 [ Regular Web Application] to Authenticate social logins.

Is this possible to use the access token created by the web application to be passed as Authorization header and get access to the web api methods?

Thanks,
Sendhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a post on Auth0 regarding [API authentication with JWT tokens on ASP.NET Core](https://auth0.com/blog/aspnet-core-apis-with-swagger-and-autorest/) and how to create clients using [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest).

The post has a [public GitHub repo](https://github.com/ealsur/auth0swagger) with the whole scenario (Web app + API) available.

Basically, you pass along the JWT token and validate it on the API with this on your Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{

/*Enabling swagger file*/

app.UseSwagger();

/*Enabling Swagger ui, consider doing it on Development env only*/

app.UseSwaggerUi();

/*It's important that this is AFTER app.UseSwagger or the swagger.json file would be innaccesible*/

var options = new JwtBearerOptions

{

    Audience = Configuration["auth0:clientId"],

    Authority = $"https://{Configuration["auth0:domain"]}/"

};

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options);

/*Normal MVC mappings*/

app.UseMvc();
```

}

Comment: Thanks Matias. This helps

Comment: OK, I'm confused big time.  it seems EVERYONE is passing a JwtBearerOptions object into a method that doesn't take that object - the app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication - which takes JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions instead.  Are there any working examples of how to do this?  (Auth0's site also says to use the above code)  I'm on .Net 4.7 if that matters

Comment: @traderhutGames - this is for .net core I think, it works different in .net 4.7